# S3 bucket with same CNAME as app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, elastic-ip

I have the following setup:

- Domain registered `mydomain.com`
- App hosted on EC2 webserver on port 80 that's a accessible right now at `mydomain.com/myapp`
- `.csv` files hosted on an S3 bucket named `myapp` at the following endpoint like so: `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myapp/sample_file.csv`
- Route 53 to deal with `CNAME` for my domain and an Elastic IP

Everything works fine. However, now I want to update the URL's in my app to mask the longer AWS prefix and replace it instead with: `mydomain.com/myapp/sample_file.csv`

Every tutorial I've seen deals with subdomains like: `myapp.mydomain.com/sample_file.csv` which I **DON'T** want (since this particular app should only be accessed at the `/myapp` URL)

Is this possible?

Comment: Which weserver/appserver software is running on your EC2 instance?

Comment: Your domain can *either* point at EC2 or at S3, you'll need to pick one. Alternatively, you could CloudFront in front of the app and send traffic to different origins based on the path. Would you be willing to use a URL like 'files.domain.com/myapp/sample_file.csv` to point to S3? That's easier since it's a different DNS name.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes. Something like `dl.mydomain.com/myapp/file.csv` would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point a custom domain name to your Amazon S3 bucket. The basic steps are:

- Create an Amazon S3 bucket with a name that matches your domain name (eg `dl.mydomain.com`)
- Activate Static Website Hosting on the bucket
- Create a Record Set in Amazon Route 53 for the `dl` subdomain:

  - Type `A`
  - Alias = yes
  - Select the Static website for your bucket

Details: [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Then, put objects in the bucket within the `myapp` directory, eg `myapp/file.csv`. You will then be able to access the file via: `dl.mydomain.com/myapp/file.csv`